# Building modules with linux kernel for custom flavor

Tags: operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel

I followed the instructions given in the link: http://blog.avirtualhome.com/how-to-compile-a-new-ubuntu-11-04-natty-kernel/  for building a custom kernel and booting it. Everything works fine, except that when building it, I used the option skipmodule=true (as given in this link), so I guess the modules are not built for this kernel. So I have two questions:

1. How do I build only the modules for my flavor, now that I have the rest of the kernel built? 'make modules' will build it for generic flavor only, if I'm not wrong.
2. Also does it require me to build the entire kernel source, 'fakeroot debian/rules binary-i5' (i5 is my custom falvor), each time I make a change to one of my modules?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) No, you don't have to rebuild the kernel every time you change a module.  2) Do all of your kernel modules fail to load?  Just some of them?  Have you already tried loading *any* of them?  Is "insmod -f" an option?

Comment: I haven't yet tried insmod, because when I run 'ls -l' in the /lib/modules/2.6.38-11-i5 folder, all the files/folders except the 'kernel' folder have got updated (Btw, I had built it last time and it had worked fine,this is an update on the same kernel source). Hence I thought there's some option/command that I missed that exports the modules as well. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ^This is after building the source and then installing the image with dpkg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) To build a linux kernel module for a specific kernel from the module source directory do:
`` make -C {path-to-kernel-source} M=`pwd` modules ``

The -C option tells is used to point to the kernel source tree where it finds the kernel's top-level Makefile. The M=`pwd` option points it to the module source directory, where it builds the 'modules' target.

2) Nope, its not necessary to build the source kernel. Either having the kernel source tree or the kernel headers suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, my module has got exported to /lib when I installed the new kernel image. Guess the timestamp of the parent directory '/lib/modules/2.6.38-11-i5/kernel' doesn't get updated. Anyway, its working fine now.   But when I make any changes to the module and do a build as you have suggested above, I get an error (as in this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/9425523/should-i-care-that-the-symbol-version-dump-is-missing-how-do-i-get-one). The solution in that post seems to suggest that we have to rebuild the kernel. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Okay it works fine now. Don't have to compile the kernel at all. Just had to give the path to build directory to make: make -C /lib/modules/2.6.38-11-i5/build M=$(PWD) modules. Thanks.